# How to continue loop every time an exception is encountered and break upon completion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to receive a promise and update the DOM with it, but there is 3 in 10 chance that the promise throws an exception. What I'm trying to do is to keep trying every time an exception is thrown and break when no exception is encountered.

I tried making a while loop that should continue upon an exception and break upon success, but it repeats anyway. I can't figure out how to make a while loop work in an asynchronous environment.

```js
      for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        while (true) {
          try {
        this.props.someServer.allMessages(this.state.someId,this.state.input);
        this.setState({input: ''});
          }
          catch (Exception) {
            console.log ("error, exception encountered, trying again.");
            continue;
          }
          break;
          console.log ("success!");
        }
      }
```

I expect it to `try` every time an exception is encountered, and break out of the loop if no exception is thrown (with a maximum of 10 tries to avoid an infinite loop).

Comment: It could be that the `catch` does not get called since you are calling a function that comes from the `props`. What happens if you await the `allMessages()` call? Make sure to return a promise in the function definition of `allMessages()`.

Comment: can you post the code for `allMessages` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `await` before the asynchronous function to wait for it to finish before you can execute the next statements.

```
await this.props.allMessages(..)
```

And make sure to wrap the while loop in an `async` function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I could have sworn I used async/await but to no avail, now I kind of feel like a moron.

None the less your answer worked great!